# Setting disable all of the components in a JSF page

Tags: jsf-2, managed-bean

I want to set disable all of the components in a page in JSF.How to do that in Managed bean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give all components that you want to disable a disabled flag with a boolean in the bean which indicates if the fields are enabled or not

```
<someTag disabled="#{yourBean.disabled}" />
```

Comment: Any other way  for setting in bean?

Comment: It takes long setting one by one.

Comment: what do you think of? post a code example of what you tried, so everyone can see what you think of and what you tried.

Comment: I am asking that is there any way to set in a method in javabean

Comment: You could try to get through all components in the UIViewRoot, but i do not think that this is the best possible way, because not all elements need to be disabled or are able to be disabled. just add the flag and a method as a switch and you're good to go